# How to connect backend create user function to front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am struggling in figuring out how to have a front-end that corresponds to my back-end in creating a user. I've successfully managed to create a user (can post to MongoDB using Insomnia) but don't know what's the structure for creating a user in the front end. Here's what my code looks like:

Router

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // First Validate The Request
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }

    // Check if this user already exisits
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
        return res.status(400).send('That user already exisits!');
    } else {
        // Insert the new user if they do not exist yet
        user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        await user.save();
        res.send(user);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

`app.use('/api/users', users);`

Answer (score 0):

Post request to this the API:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/api/users',
  data: {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    password: 'Something'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios for example, an popular library: https://github.com/axios/axios

`axios.post("URL", { email: "myemail@mail.com" })`

Answer (score 0):

What you should do, is store information the user types in your frontend in a variable and pass this data to the fetch's function via the `post` method.

```
// User information
let username = 'boneless';

// Options for your request
let options = { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({username: username});

let request = await fetch('url', { options });

let response = await request;

// Now you can apply logic to your response. Based on how your server replies.
```

*I recommend reading up on [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), as it's native in most browsers.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `POST` request to the server (`API ENDPOINT URL`) from your `frontend` (react), you can achieve this using `fetch api` or `axios`

using `fetch api` ([example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data)) -

```
function createUser(userData) {
   try {
      const response = await fetch('API_ENDPOINT_URL', {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
         body: JSON.stringify(userData)
      })
      return response.json()
   }
   catch(error) {
     // handle error 
   }
}
```

using axios - ([example](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example))

```
function createUser(userData) {
   axios.post('API_ENDPOINT_URL', userData)
      .then((response)=> {
         return response.json()
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
         // handle error
      })
 }
```

Comment: @süleyman-eminbəyli, feel free to comment, if still facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of issues with the code:

1. The code references a `validate` function, but it is not defined in the provided code snippet. It seems like this function is used to validate the request body. To fix this, you should ensure that the `validate` function is defined and correctly handles the validation of the request body.
2. The code uses `User.findOne()` to check if a user with the provided email already exists. However, the `User` model is not imported in the code snippet, so `User` is not defined. To fix this, make sure to import the `User` model and use it to interact with the database.

Assuming the missing parts are implemented elsewhere in the codebase, the corrected code would be:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Assuming 'validate' function is properly defined elsewhere in the codebase

const User = require('../models/user'); // Assuming the correct path to the User model

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // First Validate The Request
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }

    // Check if this user already exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
        return res.status(400).send('That user already exists!');
    } else {
        // Insert the new user if they do not exist yet
        user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        await user.save();
        res.send(user);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Note: The above corrections assume that the missing `validate` function and the `User` model are properly defined and implemented elsewhere in the codebase.